# Turtlebot 2 errors

Tags: turtlebot2, turtlebot, turtlebot-bringup, keyboard-teleop, groovy-turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Updated:**
I removed everything from the turtlebot laptop and installed Ubuntu 12.04, installed ros-groovy-desktop and went through debs installation for the TurtleBot.

1. I do not get errors with bringup now but I get this warning

   process[app_manager-11]: started with pid [6649]
   [WARN] [WallTime: 1362386890.272856] Battery : unable to check laptop battery info [/proc/acpi/battery/BAT0 does not exist]
   [WARN] [WallTime: 1362386890.277911] Battery : unable to check laptop battery state [/proc/acpi/battery/BAT0 does not exist].
2. Now, the dashboard looks like this

[image: image description]

With tele-op, it is still the same. I am not able to move it around. The controls do not work.

The kuboki base doesn't seem to be recognized. Why is that ? Is there a mistake I am doing ?

Thanks, Prasanna.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56704/turtlebot-2-errors/) by [prasanna.kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2416/prasanna.kumar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1363 on 2013-02-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2013-03-04**:
Can you you see the robot green LED? Sorry, I know this sounds like a stupid question, but Kobuki has a switch to change between firmware updates (no LED) and normal running. Maybe your switch is on "download" mode.

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2013-03-04**:
And another basic thing to check is whether port /dev/kobuki exists when the robot is plugged (don't need to be on)

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2013-03-04**:
The warning is probably because you are using a different laptop than the default the turtlebot is configured for. There is some information about netbook batteries on the wiki: http://ros.org/wiki/turtlebot/Tutorials/groovy/Netbook%20Battery%20Setup

**Comment by [prasanna.kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2416/prasanna.kumar/) on 2013-03-04**:
@jorge The switch is in "operation" mode only and /dev/kobuki does not exist. What may be the problem ?

**Comment by [prasanna.kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2416/prasanna.kumar/) on 2013-03-05**:
@Daniel Stonier under /proc/acpi there is nothing named battery. So basically there is no /proc/acpi/battery.

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2013-03-05**:
Did you execute this command after installation?  rosrun kobuki_ftdi create_udev_rules  (you will need root password; and upgrade ros-groovy-kobuki if the script is missing)

**Comment by [prasanna.kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2416/prasanna.kumar/) on 2013-03-06**:
@Daniel Stonier Thanks! I guess that should work once  tag bug is fixed. And, I am sorry if this sounds too naive, how do I edit a ros wiki page?

**Comment by [prasanna.kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2416/prasanna.kumar/) on 2013-03-07**:
@Daniel Stonier I tried setting the battery to /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0 but now I am getting a warning tha /sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/info is missing.

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2013-03-10**:
Just create an account for the wiki and you can start editing pages. Are you sure you set BAT0 (not BAT1) correctly?

**Comment by [Chik](https://answers.ros.org/users/3814/chik/) on 2013-03-13**:
If I were you, I would contact the distributor (Clearpath?) and ask them to send a guy to your lab to fix everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is http://askubuntu.com/questions/214379/where-did-proc-acpi-battery-bat0-xxx-go-in-12-10 relevant for you? If that works, update the battery setup wiki page with a hint and ticket us at https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot/issues?state=open

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) with karma: 3170 on 2013-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1